# how to use ajax to perform php background submission in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Hi i'm trying to converting my form data to pdf like below.
HTML -> AJAX -> PHP (fpdf)

After click submit button ajax processing & pop message as "localhost say : ok"
if i not full any input name in html , ajax pop say "please fill all fields."

why ajax not able to reach php did i done any thing wrong in php, please help.

Below  my code :

html code :

`enter code here`

```
    <form  id="form">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group container"" >
                       <center> <b>E-FSR Reporting</b>
                                <p name="date" id="date"></p>
                       </center>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" >
                  </div>
                </div>

<div class="row">
                  <div class="col-12 ">
                    <td  colspan="2" align="center" >
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="                         Submit E-FSR                      " class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 py-2 px-4">
                    </td>
                  <span class="submitting"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>

ajax code :  script.js


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var name= $("#name").val();
var dataString = 'name='+ name;
if(name=='')
{
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "pdf.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});


php code : pdf.php

    enter code here

<?php

if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    
        require("fpdf/fpdf.php");

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
....
```

Thanks

Comment: try data:{name:name} instead of data:dataString

Answer (score 0):

You are sending you data in a incorrect way:

```
Your javascript code should be like this:

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var name= $("#name").val();
if(name=='')
{
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "pdf.php",
data:{
name:name
},
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

Remark:in php when you fetch data from the $_POST the key should be like how you sent it from ajax.
From example in ajax you are writing

```
data:{
name:fname,
gender:mygender
}
```

Then in php it should be $_POST["name"] and $_POST["gender"].

Comment: Well,it worked with me. Can you please tell me what server you are using??

Comment: Are you using Apache?? And also can you please show me what it gives you on the console when you press the button?